# Finding first instance of a relationship between elements in two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have two lists, say:

```
A = {1,5,10,200,50,7}
B = {4,3,19,78}
```

For each element in A, I would like to find the index of the first element in B which exceeds that element, (or 0 if none do) i.e. :

```
result = {1,3,3,0,4,3}
```

Clever syntax much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for all the great suggestions, all helping to educate this newbie in different ways. I ought to have mentioned that my particular need here isn't performance critical and only needed for small lists, but thanks for the answers addressing the general case too.

Answer (score 7):

This is a compiled solution that should be very fast.

```
Clear@firstInstance;
With[{part = Compile`GetElement},
    firstInstance = Compile[{{A, _Integer, 1}, {B, _Integer, 1}},
        Module[{res = Table[0, {Length[A]}], i = 1, j = 1, 
            lenA = Length[A], lenB = Length[B]},
            For[i, i <= lenA, i++,
                While[part[A, i] >= part[B, j], If[j == lenB, j = 0; Break[], j++]];
                res[[i]] = j;
                j = 1;
            ];
            res
        ],
        CompilationTarget -> "C",
        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
]
```

Use it as `firstInstance[A, B]`

Comment: +1. I should now be wary that my monopoly on ugly compiled code has been broken :).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I watch and learn... and then sneak up from behind! :D

Comment: That's what I noticed :). Then, a little bit of advice: `ConstantArray` is not compilable, use `Table` instead.

Comment: Aha! Thanks, I should've checked the result... it does have `MainEvaluate[ Hold[ConstantArray][ I0, I3]]` that I should've spotted.

Comment: Well, normally this won't affect the performance all that much, depends on the code in question. Usually you can gain a few percent speedup this way, sometimes more.

Comment: Nice.  Even without `CompilationTarget -> "C"` and `GetElement` (v7) this is faster than my attempt at optimization. +1

Answer (score 5):

```
 a = {1, 5, 10, 200, 50, 7};
 b = {4, 3, 19, 78};
 Position[#, -1, 1, 1] & /@ (Sign@(# - b) & /@ a) /. {} -> {0} // Flatten
 (* {1, 3, 3, 0, 4, 3} *)
```

**Update:** Per whuber's suggestion, removing out-of-order elements from `b`, and re-mapping position numbers using a parallel list of position indices:

```
With[{b0 = FoldList[Max, First@b, Rest@b]},
 indices = Pick[Range@Length@b, MapThread[ Equal, {b, b0}]]; 
 (Position[#, -1, 1, 1] & /@ (Sign@(# - Union@b0) & /@ a) /. {} -> {{0}} // Flatten)
   /.Thread[Range@Length@indices -> indices]]
```

Few more alternatives for creating `indices`:

```
indices2 = Pick[Range@Length@b, Equal @@@ Transpose[{b, b0}]]
(* as suggested by J.M:  *)
indices3=Fold[If[#1 === {}||Last[b[[#1]]] < b[[#2]],Append[#1, #2], #1] &,{}, 
          Range[Length[b]]]
```

Comment: (+1) This has optimal efficiency `O(Length[a] Log[Length[b]]`. If you want the ultimate (asymptotic, general purpose) speedup, first pre-process `b` (with `O(Length(b))` effort) to remove out-of-order elements altogether, because *they will never be found*. Notice in the example, for instance, that the target for the position searches only has to be `b0={4,19,78}` with the `3` omitted. Easy preprocessing produces this shortened vector along with a parallel list of indexes, `{1,3,4}`, which will convert indexes into `b0` into indexes into `b`.

Comment: @whuber, great suggestions. I will check if i can incorporate them in the next edit.

Comment: FWIW, Here is my first attempt at the preprocessing, in case it's any use. I'm sure you can do better :-). `indexes = 
 Select[Range[Length[b]] (Boole[# > 0] & /@ 
     Differences[FoldList[Max, First[b] - 1, b]]), # > 0 &]; b0 = Union[FoldList[Max, First[b], b]];`. I expect `Union` to be (sub)linear in `length[b]` because its argument is already sorted.

Comment: Another way to do @whuber's suggestion: `Fold[If[#1 === {} || Last[b[[#1]]] < b[[#2]], Append[#1, #2], #1] &, {}, Range[Length[b]]]`.

Comment: @J.M., whuber thank you both. I added few alternatives for creating the index set including your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

One quick way is :

```
If[Length[#] == 0, 0, #[[1, 1]]] & /@ (With[{Local = #}, 
 Position[B, _?(# > Local &)]] & /@ A)
```

Another using Mr.Wizard's suggestion :

```
Flatten[If[Or @@ # == False, 0, 
Position[#, True, 1, 
 1]] & /@ (With[{Local = #}, Thread[B > Local]] & /@ A)]
```

Comment: Excellent, much appreciated.

Comment: It would be better to use the fourth argument of `Position` to short-circuit the search on the first find.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I had forgotten about it.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {1, 5, 10, 200, 50, 7};
b = {4, 3, 19, 78};

Mod[
  1 + Table[LengthWhile[b, # <= i &], {i, a}],
  Length@b + 1
]
```

> ```
>  {1, 3, 3, 0, 4, 3}
> ```

---

Here is a first attempt to create an efficient solution for long `b` lists.

I decided to experiment with something I'm not really comfortable with, but Leonid mentioned once: using a side-effect in `PatternTest`.  It strikes me as quite obfuscated but maybe that is only because I don't expect it.

```
  untilLarger[a_, b_] :=
    Module[{dat, min, max, f, test, m = -∞},
      test[x_] /; x > m := (Sow[m = x]; True);
      dat = Join @@@ Reap[Position[b, _?test]]\[Transpose];
      {min, max} = dat[[{1, -1}, 2]];
      f[n_] /; n < min = 1;
      f[n_] /; n >= max = 0;
      f[n_] := Cases[dat, {y_, x_} /; x > n, 1, 1][[1, 1]];
      f /@ a
    ]

untilLarger[a, b]
```

> ```
>  {1, 3, 3, 0, 4, 3}
> ```

Comment: +1. We were obviously thinking along the same direction.

Comment: Your second solution doesn't give the right result. For example, try with `{a, b} = {{8, 2, 17, 4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 4, 2}, {5, 6, 4, 9, 10, 9, 8, 0, 3, 5}}` and manually work out the answer for the fifth element in `a`. I believe this is fixed by checking for `>=` instead of `>`. However, making this change leads to other issues with duplicates in longer lists and `Interpolation` complains. For an example of a case where `Interpolation` fails, try: `SeedRandom[1234];
X = RandomInteger[{0, 20}, 10^3]; Y = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 10^6];`

Comment: @R.M I rewrote the second method to use `Cases` instead of `Interpolation` as I got the intervals wrong with the latter.  Please tell me if it works correctly now.

Comment: It does. Both our solutions have different limiting factors. Yours is limited by the length of `b`, whereas mine is limited by that of `a`. I'm still surprised that it is as fast as it is, what with the `Apply`, `Position`, `Reap/Sow` and `Cases`...

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take:

```
A = {1, 5, 10, 200, 50, 7};
B = {4, 3, 19, 78};

First[Flatten[Position[B - #, _?Positive, 1, 1]] /. {} -> {0}] & /@ A
    {1, 3, 3, 0, 4, 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

[FirstPosition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FirstPosition.html?q=FirstPosition) (for versions 10.2+)

```
FirstPosition[UnitStep[B - #], 1, 0 &][[1]] & /@ A
```

> {1, 3, 3, 0, 4, 3}

```
FirstPosition[B, _?(Function[t, # <= t]), 0 &][[1]] & /@ A
```

> {1, 3, 3, 0, 4, 3}

Answer (score 1):

The only relevant elements of `B` are those that remain when taking the largest monotonous subsequence. Below `which` is a list containing the positions of the elements of that subsequence.

```
With[{which = Pick[#, Positive[Append[Differences[#], 1]]] &[Ordering[B]]},
 With[{sz1 = Length[A], sz2 = Length[which]},
  With[{ord = TakeList[Ordering[Ordering[Join[A, B[[which]]]]], {sz1, sz2}]},
   With[{counts = Differences[Prepend[Last[ord], 0]]},
    PadRight[Join @@ MapThread[ConstantArray, {which, counts}], sz1 + sz2][[First[ord]]]]]]]
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 3, 0, 4, 3}
> ```

If `B` contains duplicates then `which` contains the position of all occurences, so the correctness is a bit subtle in that case. It is the order of the arguments of `Join` that ensures it.